# parent.AddChild not working after protecting swf using SWFProtection!

Tags: actionscript-3

I usually, use SWF Protection, to protect my swf's from decompiling.
It also adds a load bar to the swf.

The problem is that I have codes like this:

```
logo= new marca();
parent.addChild(logo);
logo.mouseEnabled=false;
```

I use parent, because I need to put the movie clip above everything, because my application allows the user to add a lot of things to the stage, so a don't want anything covering the logo.

The application works well while unprotected, but If I protect it using SWF Protection, then, I get just white screen. Nothing appears after loading.

Is there another way, to put a movieclip above everything, without being necessery to add a ON ENTER FRAME LISTENER, to update the movieclip deph, to keep it above everything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addChildAt` instead of `addChild` to add your other clips to the stage under the logo's level.

```
var levelUnderLogo:uint = numChildren == 1 ? 0 : numChildren-2;
clipYouWantUnderTheLogo = new MovieClip();
addChildAt(clipYouWantUnderTheLogo, levelUnderLogo);
```

**edit:** You can also put every other clip inside another clip that is always under the logo.

```
var base = new MovieClip();
addChild(base);

var logo = new Logo();
addChild(logo);

// Add all your other objects into the "base" clip.
var someClipUnderTheLogo = new MovieClip();
base.addChild(someClipUnderTheLogo);
```

Comment: This wont work for me, I think, because the user can also chance the movieclip depth.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the white screen because the swf embed method is breaking in the javascript.  Basically you have a javascript error.

Because you did not post code I can't help you much more. All I can say is put alerts in the javascript and see how far you get.